# Writing a file with fixed width fields in java

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

I have three strings that I need to write into a file without any new lines and have them within fixed width fields. currently im trying to use printwriter's printf but i dont fully understand how to do it. if this isnt enough info please ask and ill do my best to clarify my question.

Comment: Do you need your newlines simply removed from the strings? And what is "within fixed with fields"?

Comment: I think he means that it should be space filled if the data cannot take the entire field (space padded) so that the field is always the same length

Answer (score 2):

If you have 3 strings, a, b and c, you should be able to use something like this...

```
printf("a=%-20s b=%-20s c=%-20s", a, b, c);
```

This will left align your strings and they will be fixed at a width of 20 each.